# Custom JsonConverter on a property based on another property value

Tags: c#, json.net

I have a physical dimension class like this:

```
public class Physical
{
  public Dimension Dimension {get; set;}
  public double Value {get; set;}
  public string Unit {get; set;}
}
```

`Dimension` is an enum with values like, `Force`, `Temperature`, `Displacement`, `Time`, etc.

and a class with `Physical` properties like

```
public class MeasurementInfo
{
  public Instrument Instrument {get; set;}
  public Physical MaxReading {get; set;}
  public Physical MinReading {get; set;}
  public Physical AmbientTemperature {get; set;}
}
```

`Instrument` is also an enum with values like `Chronometer`, `WeightScale`, `Thermometer`, `Caliper`, etc.

The `Dimension` property value of some of my `Physical` properties depends on the `Instrument` value. Other ones are fixed. Example:

```
var myMeasure = new MeasurementInfo()
{
  Instrument = Instrument.WeightScale,
  MaxReading = new Physical()
  {
    Dimension = Dimension.Weight,
    Value = 100.0,
    Unit = "kg"
  },
  MinReading = new Physical()
  {
    Dimension = Dimension.Weight,
    Value = 50.0,
    Unit = "kg"
  },
  AmbientTemperature = new Physical()
  {
    Dimension = Dimension.Temperature,
    Value = 27,
    Unit = "°C"
  }
};
```

What I want is to save this object as JSON like this:

```
{
  "Instrument": "Weight Scale",
  "Max Reading": "100 kg",
  "Min Reading": "50 kg",
  "AmbientTemperature": "27 °C"
}
```

Serialization is easy as we have `Value` and `Unit` defined. My problem is with deserialization because I have to read the `Instrument` value to determine a `Dimension` to recreate the `Physical` objects.

My actual try is using a `ContractResolver`. This way I can define my `JsonConverter` based on the property type and name.

```
public class MyContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
  protected override JsonProperty CreateProperty(MemberInfo member, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
  {
    JsonProperty result = base.CreateProperty(member, memberSerialization);
    if(result.PropertyType == typeof(Physical))
    {
      var property = member as PropertyInfo;
      switch (result.PropertyName)
      {
        case "AmbientTemperature":
          result.Converter = new JsonPhysicalConverter(Dimension.Temperature);
          break;
        case "MaxReading":
        case "MinReading":
          result.Converter = new JsonPhysicalConverter(???);
          break;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The ??? is where I got stuck. The `ContractResolver` doesn't work for instances so I can't know beforehand my `Instrument` value.

Comment: Sorry I may not have made the question clear enough so looked like a duplicate

Comment: Will you share the serialization code please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `JsonConverter` does not have access to the parent of the object that it is handling.  So if the converter handles `Physical` it won't be able to "see" the `Instrument` inside `MeasurementInfo`.

So there are two approaches I can see:

1. Make the converter handle the parent `MeasurementInfo` in addition to `Physical`.  The converter will then be able to see the `Instrument` and create `Physical` as needed.
2. Use the unit value to determine the appropriate `Dimension`.  For example, if the unit is `kg` you know the dimension must be `Weight`, regardless of the instrument, right?  This would only break down if there are two units which look the same but represent different dimensions depending on the instrument.  But based on your examples, I don't think this would be the case.  This approach would be "cleaner" in my opinion.

---

Here is an example of the first approach:

```
public class MeasurementInfoConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(MeasurementInfo);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        JObject obj = JObject.Load(reader);
        MeasurementInfo info = new MeasurementInfo();
        info.Instrument = obj["Instrument"].ToObject<Instrument>(serializer);
        info.MinReading = ReadPhysical(obj, "Min Reading", info.Instrument);
        info.MaxReading = ReadPhysical(obj, "Max Reading", info.Instrument);
        info.AmbientTemperature = ReadPhysical(obj, "Ambient Temperature", Instrument.Thermometer);
        return info;
    }

    private Physical ReadPhysical(JObject obj, string name, Instrument instrument)
    {
        Dimension dim = Dimension.Force;
        switch (instrument)
        {
            case Instrument.WeightScale: dim = Dimension.Weight; break;
            case Instrument.Chronometer: dim = Dimension.Time; break;
            case Instrument.Thermometer: dim = Dimension.Temperature; break;
            case Instrument.Caliper:     dim = Dimension.Displacement; break;
        }
        string[] parts = ((string)obj[name]).Split(new char[] { ' ' }, 2);
        Physical physical = new Physical()
        {
            Dimension = dim,
            Value = double.Parse(parts[0]),
            Unit = parts[1]
        };
        return physical;
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        MeasurementInfo info = (MeasurementInfo)value;
        JObject obj = new JObject();
        obj.Add("Instrument", JToken.FromObject(info.Instrument, serializer));
        WritePhysical(obj, "Min Reading", info.MinReading);
        WritePhysical(obj, "Max Reading", info.MaxReading);
        WritePhysical(obj, "Ambient Temperature", info.AmbientTemperature);
        obj.WriteTo(writer);
    }

    private void WritePhysical(JObject obj, string name, Physical physical)
    {
        obj.Add(name, physical.Value.ToString("N0") + " " + physical.Unit);
    }
}
```

Working round-trip demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/ZUibQ1

---

For completeness, here is an example of the second approach:

```
public class PhysicalConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(Physical);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        string value = (string)reader.Value;
        string[] parts = value.Split(new char[] { ' ' }, 2);
        Dimension dim;
        if (!DimensionsByUnit.TryGetValue(parts[1], out dim)) dim = Dimension.Force;
        Physical physical = new Physical()
        {
            Dimension = dim,
            Value = double.Parse(parts[0]),
            Unit = parts[1]
        };
        return physical;
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        Physical physical = (Physical)value;
        writer.WriteValue(physical.Value.ToString("N0") + " " + physical.Unit);
    }

    private static Dictionary<string, Dimension> DimensionsByUnit = new Dictionary<string, Dimension>
    {
        { "mg", Dimension.Weight },
        { "g", Dimension.Weight },
        { "kg", Dimension.Weight },
        { "°C", Dimension.Temperature },
        { "°F", Dimension.Temperature },
        { "°K", Dimension.Temperature },
        { "µs", Dimension.Time },
        { "ms", Dimension.Time },
        { "s", Dimension.Time },
        { "mm", Dimension.Displacement },
        { "cm", Dimension.Displacement },
        { "m", Dimension.Displacement },
    };
}
```

Working round-trip demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/1ecLNJ

Comment: Thanks. The classes here are hypothetical. The real ones are way more complex. The physical handles unit conversion and operations with different dimensions (dividing displacement with time and saving  with speed, for example). The real main class handles other dimensions (fixed). I will try to make an example of my approach

Comment: I'm trying to use the first approach, could you make some simple example?

Comment: @RodrigoMartins OK, I have added examples of both approaches.

Comment: Man, that's what I call a pretty code. Thank you very much!

Comment: No problem; glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

Use anonymous object:

```
        var objectToBeSerialized = new
        {
            Instrument = myMeasure.Instrument.ToString(),
            MaxReading = $"{myMeasure.MaxReading.Value} {myMeasure.MaxReading.Unit}",
            MinReading = $"{myMeasure.MinReading.Value} {myMeasure.MinReading.Unit}"
        };
```

and convert this object into JSON using NewtonSoft.Json library:

```
        var serializedJSON = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(objectToBeSerialized);
```

Comment: Serialize is not the problem. I can't deserialize without knowing the Dimension beforehand